# Opening a spinner dropdown menu from an ImageButton on Android

Tags: android, spinner, android-imagebutton

My layout contains a spinner and an ImageButton.
The spinner is setup properly. Pressing on it displays the drop down menu.
Now I'm trying to add an onClick action on my button so it can open the Spinner

The following code:

```
this.imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            spinner.performClick();
        }
    });
```

works fine on the genymotion emulator, but not on my Nexus 4 & 6 devices.
On those devices the dropdown menu opens then closes automatically. Every 10-20 attempts it might remain open but that's it.

Any idea what's going on ?
How can I prevent this ?

Edit if I enable android:spinnerMode="dialog" instead of thde default 'dropdown' it works fine, as if something was taking the focus from the spinner... What's strange is that opening the dropdown menu by pressing on the spinner works fine

Comment: Please check my question. As you can see I already posted the interesting code...

Answer (score 0):

Here is Source Hope so It works,

```
final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
Button okButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yesButton);
okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(spinner.getSelectedItem() == null) { // user selected nothing...
            spinner.performClick();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This is already what I'm using (see the code in my question). It works fine but the dropdown menu gets automatically closed after a fraction of second, when opened like that (see my edit)